# Reconnect TCPClient after interruption

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have multiple instances of a client application, connecting to a main application over internet by TcpClient. (Both coded by me). So the connection is made like:

TcpClient.Connect(ip, port)

I now want this to handle various type of disconnect events:

1. Main App (server) or a client app computer lose internet connection.

   - On resume of connection, the communication seems lost, but when I try to reconnect, I get message: 
     **"A connection request was made on an already connected socket"**
   - So I need to close and restart the client app.
2. Main App (server) is closed, and restarted.

   - Restarting the Main App, and then trying to reconnect the client app, results in same error as above.

So, what do I need to do?  Do I need to instantiate a New TcpClient in the Client Apps, whenever such interruption occur? I haven't tried that, so don't know if that's a poor solution?

Comment: Have a look over my solution: https://github.com/Mellen/Networking-Samples

Comment: No, do not look at that client example. Don't use threads to read in the background. Use the asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> do I need to instantiate a New TcpClient in the Client Apps, whenever such interruption occur?

Yes. If the connection represented by the TcpClient is broken, you can't use that object for further communicating, nor can you connect it again. Create a new TcpClient object.

Your problem is likely that a NAT gateway times out your TCP connection, so nothing can get through between your server<->client, if all your client does is read from the connection, it will not discover this case, and it thinks the connection is still open.

Comment: Thanks!  I plan to check the connection from the client app, every 5 sec or so. Not sure how, either by sending a standard message that should give a certain response, or maybe there is some method already on the TcpClient object I can use?  Then this should discover any disconnect, and then I can instantiate a new TcpClient and reconnect. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes. send some kind of heartbeat on the connection and wait(with a timeout) for a reply

Answer (score 1):

I have typically solved this problem before in the past by using threads.  I created a control thread that loops through and does administrative things like, check the connection, check the latest user input, check a server shutdown request, etc.  When it is done it slept for half a second and did it all over again.

I then had a seperate Socket thread that was created and simply maintained a network socket.  It would open the connection once started and loop repeatedly looking for incoming messages from whoever it was connected to.  If it found a message it would process it and store it in a volatile object collection for consumption by the control thread.  If something happened to the connection it would automatically try to resolve and if it couldn't it would go into a 'dead' state.  The control thread at its next iteration would clean up the dead socket threads and create new ones as necessary.

Debugging was a nightmare but it was surprisingly stable once the bugs were worked out.  On one instance it ran successfully for over a year with tens of thousands of connections and hundreds of concurrent connections with no need for restarts or any maintenance whatsoever.

Comment: Cheers, I will need to work on this yes. I also require such level of stability. Currently I use AsyncCallback on the stream read, so I guess that will make it separate thread on it own. And for continuous checks, I use a timer, to fire the events, which works on it's own thread. But I need to incorporate more comprehensive checks.

Comment: Timer threads and Callback threads are nice and all, but you might have better control if you write your own threads.  Another advantage of this is that I was able to package them in their own library that both the client and server had, so that the client could run its own server for debugging purposes.  Plus I am sure there are common routines that both the client and the server could utilize.