# If no data is received over stream tcpclient close the connection

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, tcpclient

I would like to know on `TcpClient`'s `NetworkStream` what exactly happen if timeout occurs.

While debugging the code i found that after request is sent and if no data is received within mention timeout period it throws below exception and unfortunately closes the connection (`TcpClient.Connected` become false):

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.

It throws the exception is okay, but i would like to know how i can prevent it from closing the connection.

It would be great if someone can provide more insights on this.

Comment: Usually, servers are designed in the way, that forces connection closing after some inactivity time from client. This allows to utilize server resources more effectively. But looking at your message, I suppose, that it is not your case. Looks like you just can't connect to your server. Please, post MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If the connection is never completed you can't keep it open.  So I'm assuming the timeout occurred after the initial connection was made.  If the server closes the connection then you cannot prevent the connection from closing.  Often a server will close a connection when it is idle.  In that case you use the KeepAlive Option which sends a null data gram periodically to the server so the server doesn't close the conneciton.

Comment: That exception means your Connect call failed. This has nothing to do with reading. No connection has been established yet. Post code. Closing for now due to lack of code. Undiagnosable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this one? [Reconnect TCPClient after interruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910568/reconnect-tcpclient-after-interruption) I think if you have a long enough TTL of your TCP Connection, should an exception occurs (I believe you would get thrown a SocketException) you can catch that up and initiate your retry logic. There are several implementations for this and obviously that would depend on the use case but normally there is a number of attempts (configuration value) before "giving up" connecting. That way your manager will retry connecting X number of times and will carry on if there is a successful connection otherwise will propagate up in the chain the exception.